# Multi ListViews?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to figure out how to make this app since a lot of time, I'm a newbie so yeah, what for you might be easy for me is certainly harder.

After said that I'll illustrate you my question:

I'd like to make an app listing a **ListView**, with **NO** elements on itself, but, you'll be able to **add** them into it thanks to a '**+**' button.

***Behavior***:

You **click** the + button, you **insert** the name of the element, you **press** go and.. the ListView now **displays** the **element** with the name you gave it.

Now the real '*magic*' happens:

Let's say I jut created a '**Bag**' element, I have some *objects* on this bag which I want to add aswell, but that wouldn't be useful to add them in the **same** **ListView** of Bag, so:

I **click** on the '**Bag**' element, a brand *new* (empty) ListView comes out, with our special '**+**' button which will allow me to **create** the **elements** for the objects in the bag.

Just to make you understand.. I'd like the app to be *dynamic* so that if you ever have a **bag** inside a **bag**.. you can always create a **ListView** inside **another** and another...

If you didn't get the behavior of this App, please do not put 'On Hold' this question, but rather, ask questions to me, I'll be very happy to answer all of 'em!

---

IMGUR: http://imgur.com/a/lghZx

Comment: You can use ExpandableListView to achieve this effect [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and inside you expandable listview add a button and edittext to add items inside it

Comment: May I ask you a demo of it? :)

Comment: @L-X What I meant is if you could show me how to do that, thanks

Comment: Let me implement , Probably it will take time

Comment: Thanks, but wait! @L-X

Comment: What I want to do isn't just like I saw on your link, I'm uploading some iages to clarify anything, can you wait 5 minutes?

Comment: @L-X I have just added an Imgur link at the bottom of my question, hope that will explain my idea of the app

Comment: Just to know that.. you saw the images @L-X ?

Comment: I have posted my answer take a look and , if you have problem understanding anything just ask, my advise will be to write this whole code yourself instead of copying and pasting you will understand it more

Answer (score 1):

First it is not advisable to have listview inside a listview , as it creates scrolling problem .ExpandableListView is recommended

Preview:
[image]

Now in this tutorial you will be able to add list item and sub list item with edittext , Lets start with defining layouts

1.Define ExpandableListView tag in activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_item_et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:onClick="addItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />
</LinearLayout>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/parent_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

2. Define layout for outer list list_group.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="8dp"
       android:background="#000000">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
       android:textSize="17dp"
       android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Create layout for child list (We will have to different layout for child)

list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

list_item_2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_child_list_et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_child_list_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

4. Define ExpandableListView in MainActivity.java

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ```
   private ExpandableListView elv;
   private ExpandableListAdapter adapter;
   private List<String> listDataHeader;//This is main List
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;//This is child list
   private EditText addHeaders;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

       elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.parent_list_view);
       addHeaders=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_item_et);
       init();

       adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);//This is a custom adapter that we will define shortly

       elv.setAdapter(adapter);


   }

   private void init() {

       listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
       listDataChild=new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 

       //Just creating one item in our list to start with something
       listDataHeader.add(new String("Header 1"));
       List<String> subHeaderOne=new ArrayList<String>();
       subHeaderOne.add("");//Create First item always empty as we will have different layout for this
       subHeaderOne.add("Header1 SubHeading 1");   

       listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), subHeaderOne);

   }

   public void addItem(View v) {
       //We will add new item in listDataHeader and also in listDataChild
       String header="";
       header=addHeaders.getText().toString();
       if(header.length()>1){
           listDataHeader.add(header);
           List<String> childList=new ArrayList<String>();
           childList.add("");//necessary to have atleast one empty item in our child list where we will set different layout
           listDataChild.put(header, childList);
       }

       addHeaders.setText("");
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }

    }
   ```
5. Now the Dirty part defining our own custom adapter ExpandableListAdapter.java

   ```
   public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

   private List<String> listDataHeader;
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
   private Context context;

   public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
           List<String> listDataHeader,
           HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
           this.listDataHeader=listDataHeader;
           this.listDataChild=listDataChild;
           this.context=context;
   }

   @Override
   public int getGroupCount() {
       return listDataHeader.size();
   }

   @Override
   public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       return listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
       return listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
   }


   @Override
   public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
       return groupPosition;
   }



   @Override
   public boolean hasStableIds() {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
           View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final String headerText=(String) getGroup(groupPosition);
       if(convertView==null){
           LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
       }

       TextView txtListHeader=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
       txtListHeader.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
       txtListHeader.setText(headerText);
       return convertView;
   }



   @Override
   public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition,
           boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final String childText=(String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

       if(convertView!=null)convertView=null;// If we remove this line then there was problem , Haven't figured it out , its temp solution



       if(convertView==null){
           LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

           switch(childPosition){
           case 0:     
               //If child item is the first item in sub list ,we will set layout which contain EditText and button so to add more item in sub list(child list)
               convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, null);
               convertView.setId(0);
               break;
           default:
               //If child item is any other than first item in sub list ,we will set layout which contain just TextView
               convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
               convertView.setId(1);
           }

       }

       int viewId=convertView.getId();

       switch(viewId){
       case 0:
           final EditText editText=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_child_list_et);
           Button addButton=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_child_list_bt);

           addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   String txt="";

                   txt=editText.getText().toString();
                   List<String> newList=listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
                   newList.add(txt);
                   editText.setText("");
                   notifyDataSetChanged();


               }
           });
           break;
       case 1:
           TextView txtListChild=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
           txtListChild.setText(childText+" "+childPosition);
           break;
       }




       return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return (listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition);
   }


   @Override
   public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return childPosition;
   }

    }
   ```

Feel Free to ask anything

Comment: I decided to first make anything work and then to understand clearly what was going on, but when I paste all the code I get a bunch of errors, what am I doing wrong? (2 Classes and 4 Xml layout files) @L-X

Comment: Make sure you have imported all the classes that are used here , I haven't included them ,tell me all the errors and try to write whole code by yourself

Comment: Yes I thought about that at first, that's why I turned auto imports ON, but nothing seems to work. By the way, would you prefer to contact me somewhere else and then post back here the correct solution so that we will keep it here clear? @L-X

Comment: Uhm @L-X I think I didn't explained myself clearly, you got the app for half, I mean yeah it should do that.. but not like that.. it's more a UI misunderstanding (bad explanation I know) Have you checked the images I did upload? (Link on the question)

Comment: Thanks, I will also on as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a `EditText` view in your screen where people can add the objects with a `Button`. Then you just make the `onClickListener` from that button also update the `Adapter` that was added to your `ListView`.

Comment: Yes, but consider that whenever I click on any element, there should be (maybe thanks to `fragments`) a new `EditText` and button for a new `ListView`

Comment: You can add a layout file to a adapter so when you put the EditText and Button in there it will make every row have an EditText and a Button